# how to change color in click and remove color clicked one second click fullcalendar reactjs

Tags: jquery, reactjs, fullcalendar

**I have a calendar in v5 using React.JS.**

**I have a function like this**

```
function handleChangeBackgroundColorCalendar (info) {
  info.el.style.backgroundColor = 'red'
}
```

*This function makes me click on the cell of the calendar and the color is really changed. How do I click again and go back to the initial color of the calendar?*

- If I click for the first time, the color should be red
- If I click again, the color should be blue
- If I click again, the color should be red and so on

I call the function JSX like this:

```
<FullCalendar
  id="calendar"
  ref={calendarRef}
  slotMaxTime="22:00:00"
  slotMinTime="07:00:00"
  allDaySlot={false}
  eventClick={info => {
    handleChangeBackgroundColorCalendar(info)
  }}

  plugins={[resourceTimeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin]}
  defaultView="resourceTimeGridDay"
  editable={false}
  selectable={true}
  selectMirror={true}
  schedulerLicenseKey={'GPL-My-Project-Is-Open-Source'}
  dayMaxEvents={true}
  weekends={weekendsVisible}
  events={handleLoadInformationsCalendar()}
  themeSystem={'bootstrap'}
  headerToolbar={{
    left: '',
    center: '',
    right: ''
  }}
  locale="pt-br"
  timeZone='America/Sao_Paulo'
/>
```

Comment: Ow, the function is info.el.style.backgroundColor = 'red', sorry

Answer (score 2):

You can define one boolean value which notifies you even/odd of the click event.

```
const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false)

...

function handleChangeBackgroundColorCalendar (info) {
 info.el.style.backgroundColor = toggle ? 'red' : 'blue'
 setToggle(!toggle)
}
```